# versioning the database with the new update in the application

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode6

I have to implement changes in the database file like adding new columns in the table.

I am using coredata.
I had create the new version for the xcdatamodel.

In this [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2150667&seqNum=2) are the steps which i perform for the creating new xcdatamodel.

```
Select Model.xcdatamodeld.

Click Editor > Add Model Version....

Click Finish to accept Model 2 as the version name.
```

My question is does this step will help me to implement the changes of the database without deleting the data from it.
 when i upload new update in the iTunes.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also verify with the options for your persistent store, and you can check **Automatic Lightweight Migration** for more details.

```
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *options = @{ NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @(YES),
                               NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @(YES) };
    NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                   configuration:nil
                                                                             URL:URL
                                                                         options:options
                                                                           error:&error];
```